# Possible to use the object model to push content across two different web applications?

Tags: development, visual-studio, object-model

I've been able to use the object model to move list items between sites in the same site collection, but I'm wondering if I can use it to move list items between two different web applications on different servers?  Would I have to use web services to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If your web applications are within the same farm, you can use the
  object model to move/copy the lists between web applications. But in
  such case, both web application at least be running using the same
  application pool account, or sufficient permissions must be there on Content DBs if application pool accounts are different.
- If Web Applications are on different farms then, you can use SPServices project which makes it easier.
  http://spservices.codeplex.com/
- You can also use OOTB list service of a Web application to move the list data.

I would personally fancy the **second** option.

Comment: That wouldn't be an option to hit from a server side event (such as a custom action in a workflow) would it?

Comment: Sorry, I'm talking about #2 in my first comment.

Comment: I used SPServices to kicked off workflows in the past but I don't see an issue why they can't be used to invoke other server side events because, the whole library abstracts SharePoint's Web Services and makes them easier to use.

Comment: What i'm wondering is where you would even use a jQuery library for something like a custom workflow action.  Aren't custom workflow actions entirely defined in code behind or is there a client side component?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can solely use jQuery library for Custom work flow action but you can do some small things like starting the workflows using jQuery see: https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/4-clicks-or-1-using-jquery-to-start-a-sharepoint-workflow.aspx

Comment: However, you can combine Client side object model together with jQuery to work across Custom workflow actions.